# Your IT administrator requires a security scan of this item - *what* item?

Tags: windows-10, security, windows-defender

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 and from time to time I've been getting this notification:

[image: Security scan required]

I don't use any 3rd-party antivirus or antimalware programs, so I gather it's coming from Windows Defender.  The trouble is..

- It doesn't tell me *what* item.
- There's no apparent way to take any action, whether I approve this or not.
- I've already tried excluding my code folder from Windows Defender, but that's made no difference so far.

How can I find out what item it's so concerned about?  And what am I supposed to do with this notification?

Comment: What does the eventlog say?

Comment: @LPChip I can't find anything in Windows Logs.  I looked through many of the Applications and Services Logs and couldn't find anything there either.  I also tried creating a custom view to see errors and warnings for all logs over a very limited time range (just a couple of minutes based on the time of the notification), but Event Viewer apparently couldn't handle it.

Comment: I managed to create a custom view for just Windows logs, and there was nothing relevant.

Comment: I bet you need to look in: Event Viewer > Applications and Services logs > Microsoft > Windows Defender > Operational

Comment: @LPChip Actually it's Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender, but thanks for the tip!  Right there at the exact time of the warning I found: `Windows Defender Antivirus has uploaded a file for further analysis.  Filename: C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Local\NCrunch\22372\11\QueueReruns\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\[nameofmyapp].dll Sha256:`  So it was the NCrunch build of the program I was working on.  ...So now what do I do with the notification?

Comment: (I guess an obvious first step is to ignore that NCrunch folder in Defender.)

Comment: @LPChip Write your comments up into an answer and I'll accept it.  I have reasonable suspicions that ignoring the NCrunch folder will solve the problem.  Your tips helped me find it.

Comment: This item == the item currently being scanned. Misleading, but “normal”. Also had it with Go programming.

Comment: Ah, I missed the windows tread. I first went looking for if it was there, and once found it I quickly traced back the path, but missed one node... Glad you got to the end of it though... Wrote you an answer. :)

Comment: @Kyralessa - If you are the only user on the machine, in other words it's a personal machine, do nothing with the informatin. If it's a company machine, contact your IT Administrator, to adjust the Windows Defender configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, it is locking me from running the app because it is locking the MDF database. :-(  Setting Windows Defender to exclude my source folders.

Comment: I have the same issue with the output (EXE) of my VS 2019 project. I get the notification sometimes and only when debugging the program.  It is finding it in the ShadowCache and Windows Defender doesn't like it.  From the Event log:
     
    Windows Defender Antivirus has uploaded a file for further analysis.
  Filename: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_c91b605c\Designer\ShadowCache\[FUNNY_NAME]\[FUNNY_NAME]\[FILENAME].exe
  Sha256: b03abf7d2ed5a0a93e09cedb06f8d8c3930ab432a27a7548e32a74bc6663f765

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd look in the eventlog to find out what the problem is.

The path would be: 
`Event Viewer` > `Applications and Services logs` > `Microsoft` > `Windows` > `Windows Defender` > `Operational`

Comment: Look for an event with Event ID 2050 in this log.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from **LPChip**'s helpful answer, I wanted to open this folder at will from a shortcut.

It turns out Event Viewer does have a command line syntax:

*eventvwr /l:[log file path]*

or

*eventvwr /c:[channel name]*

Right-clicking and accessing the Properties of a node in Event Viewer offers the Full Name (pass to **/c:**) and Log path (pass to **/l:**), which can be passed to the command line to open Event viewer on this node so I end up with this command for my shortcut:

```
C:\Windows\System32\eventvwr.exe /c:"Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it´s VS related? If not, and you´re using Office365, this could be the [Office365 ATP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/office-365-advanced-threat-protection-e100fe7c-f2a1-4b7d-9e08-622330b83653). If this is the case, the information on this link will give you initial information on setting it up.

Comment: I have the same issue and it is ONLY happening when I run VS2019 on my project.  Been working on this for weeks and today it starts complaining everytime I attempt to build with database and Defender locks the database file so I can't access it.