# "Your administrator requires a security scan of this item. This could take up to 10 seconds."

Tags: windows-10, office365, visual-studio, windows-defender

Every time I build and run a Visual Studio project, I get this warning and my program takes much longer to start up, even for a simple hello world program. I looked around and I think this might be because I signed into an Office 365 account provided to me by my work and it is using Office ATP. However, this is a personal computer and I don't want this "protection". I have uninstalled Office 365 and signed out of my work account on the device but I am still getting this warning.

[image: scan required]

Is this office ATP related and how can I remove this permanently? I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to contact your system administrator?  Otherwise you could unlink the account from within the Settings application

Comment: I have unlinked the account from settings already. This is not a company owned device so I was hoping I wouldn't have to contact anyone from my organization.

Comment: “Is this office ATP related” - No; At least not directly it’s due to you linking your Office Account and have your company’s policies imposed on your personal machine

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1469051/your-it-administrator-requires-a-security-scan-of-this-item-what-item

Comment: Yup, I saw that. That's where I got the initial impression that it was Office ATP related. I tried to remove my device using these instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/remove-your-device-cpwebsite, but my access is denied. I think I will have to contact my company.